# Is it natural to say "it snowed for the first time yesterday" meaning the first snow fell this year yesterday?

Tags: grammar

Could you tell me if the sentence below sounds absolutely natural?

> **It snowed** for the first time yesterday, so it's wet today.

What I'm trying to say is that the first snow fell this year yesterday. Would it be more natural to say it like this

> **It was snowing** for the first time yesterday, so it's wet today?

Comment: You probably don't mean ***first time this year***, since in November you're presumably not interested in whether or not it snowed back in January. So I expect you mean ***first time this winter***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It snowed* is fine. Snow fell yesterday, it has since melted and so the ground is wet today.

> It was snowing yesterday so we didn't go out.

Here, we are talking about the weather conditions as they affected our activities yesterday.